# Using gettext in CakePHP model validation

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, methods, gettext

Is there any possibility to use the gettext functionallity within the CakePHP model validation array?

Usually a programmer would do it like this:

```
class Data extends AppModel
{
 var $validate = array(
  'title' => array(
   'NichtLeer' => array(
    'rule' => array('between', 4, 20),
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'message' => _('Bitte geben Sie einen Titel an!')
   )
  )
 );
}
```

But since it is not possible to use functions outside a method's scope, I have to find another clean alternative.

So, is there any alternative to the one, that **defines the validations improvised in the model's setup** method?

Regards,
Benedikt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building the `validate` array in the constructor could be considered a clean alternative:

```
class Data extends AppModel {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->validate = array(
            'title' => array(
                'NichtLeer' => array(
                    'rule' => array('between', 4, 20),
                    'allowEmpty' => false,
                    'message' => _('Bitte geben Sie einen Titel an!')
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, in case you may be interested, CakePHP comes with some goodies for [internationalization and localization](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1228/Internationalization-Localization).

Comment: Yes, I already use all this features :-) Thanks. I think I'll stick to this.

Comment: I only mentioned that because you used the single underscore function in your code, not the double underscore function that comes with CakePHP.

Comment: I am using the same approach as Mike's, but instead in __construct() I am setting this array in the beforeValidate(). For me it's more meaningful, but also in __construct() should work pretty much the same.